# Calculate the checksum (md5 or sh1 )of a file before upload and send the hash to server using uploadify jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, file-upload, md5, uploadify

i want to add  and send a variable i.e "Md5ofFile"  in the request with each file that are getting uploaded .

And again on server verify that the "Md5ofFile" is same as the hash of the file recived on the server other wise send a error message to client

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question how to transport the value, e.g. inside the form data, up to the server on a per file basis?

Comment: Yes HiTech Magic ..Infact i need to calculated checksum of all the sleceted file and send to the server .. again on server i need to calculate the checksum and validate if its same as send by the browser

Comment: I can help you with how to transport the values during the `uploadify` submit, as we had to upload per-file drop-down selections, but I don't know how to run a client-side file checksum from within a browser. if you can solve that I can help with part 2.

Comment: Hi HiTech magic .currently my application uses uplodify 2.1.0 . I want  use onUploadStart  method to add the file size for each file before upload . But i am not able to upgrade the uplodify to version 3 .   
can you help me in this ?


I dont find any valid resource for up gradation